# Toggle different elements using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to VueJS and I am trying to learn it.

I've made a very simple tooltip, it should appear when clicked and closed when clicked again. With just one tooltip this works well with some very basic (beginners)code.

```
<div v-if="toolTipContent.length > 0" class="c-tooltip">
      <a @click="(clicked) ? clicked = false : clicked = true" class="c-tooltip--link">
          {{ $label('toolTipLink') }}
      </a>
      <div v-html="toolTipContent" v-if="clicked" class="c-tooltip--content"></div>
</div>
```

And in JS

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      clicked: false,
      toolTipContent: global.content,
    }
  }
```

But now I want multiple tooltips. I can of coarse be a complete newbie and just copy above and change the properties and values, but that doesn't make sense.

So I am trying something like:

```
<div v-if="toolTipContent.length > 0" class="c-tooltip">
  <a @click="toggleEl" class="c-tooltip--link">
    {{ $label('toolTipLink') }}
  </a>
  <div v-html="toolTipContent" v-show="clicked" class="c-tooltip--content"></div>
</div>
```

and in JS the same as above plus:

```
methods: {
    toggleEl(e) {
      e.target.nextSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
  },
```

But I am stuck here. I mean, I can toggle a class on the next sibling (as I am doing above), but that somehow feels like a jQuery-way in Vue. So I think i'd have to use the `clicked` value, but if I do, all tooltips are shown (or hidden). Also I am using `v-show` now, whereas I'd have a feeling `v-if` should be better. But with `v-if` I can't target the content, becuase it is not part of the DOM.

What should be the recommended way to solve this?

Comment: `(clicked) ? clicked = false : clicked = true`  could be simplified to `clicked =!clicked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to keep all your tooltips and their properties (clicked, content, etc.) in the `data()` part of your Vue app.

```
<script>
...
data() {
  tooltips: [
    {
      content: content1,
      isClicked: false
    },
    {
      content: content2,
      isClicked: false
    }
  ]
},
...
</script>
```

Now you can easily render all these tooltips in the template part.

```
<div v-for="tooltip in tooltips" v-if="tooltip.content > 0" class="c-tooltip">
      <a @click="clickTooltip(tooltip)" class="c-tooltip--link">
          {{ $label('toolTipLink') }}
      </a>
      <div v-if="tooltip.clicked" class="c-tooltip--content">{{tooltip.content}}</div>
</div>
```

Notice above how we are using `tooltip` in a dynamic way as the 'current element'.

Last but not least, we need to take care of the `clickTooltip` method that we use for clicking. It's more elegant and readable to separate it in a method in the script part:

```
<script>
...
methods: {
  clickTooltip(tooltip) {
    tooltip = !tooltip
  } 
}
...
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow thought there would be a way to prevent a potential large array of tooltips in data(), but I guess there isn't, unless you'll work with show / hide classes (or something like that) and pass the value to the togglemethod.